# How to fix `ld: warning: -undefined dynamic_lookup may not work with chained fixups`on macOS M1?

Tags: c++, macos, linker, bazel, bazel-cpp

I get always the linker warning

```
ld: warning: -undefined dynamic_lookup may not work with chained fixups
```

when building my C++ project with Bazel.

```
bazel clean && bazel test --config=macos //...
```

My question is how can I fix/prevent this?

On Windows (using Visual Studio) and Linux (using GCC and Clang) this warning does not occure.

My Environment: Bazel 6.0, macOS Ventura 13.1 (Apple M1 Pro Chip)

*WORKSPACE.bazel*:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "googletest",
    sha256 = "1d5e983023e43a695d3f49ceaed4e0010baaeb4591d88532b779669dc8f6a68e",
    strip_prefix = "googletest-a652ae05755c5d95e9b11ef0c4bc0b715e4332d4",
    urls = [
        "https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/a652ae05755c5d95e9b11ef0c4bc0b715e4332d4.tar.gz",
    ],
)
```

*BUILD.bazel*:

```
cc_test(
    name = "tests",
    srcs = ["test.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "@googletest//:gtest_main",
    ],
)
```

*test.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(sample_test_case, sample_test) {
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

*.bazel.rc*:

```
build:macos --cxxopt=-std=c++2a
build:macos --cxxopt=-Wall
```

Comment: There's a relatively new version of bazel where that option is turned off on Darwin platforms. See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/16413